# How do i deploy my nextjs project on subdirectory

Tags: next.js

Recently I've developed a project with NextJs which I need to deploy it on a subdirectory, but i don't know how to do it. I've searched online, but couldn't find solution that suits me. The main directory has a WordPress site. In NextJs config file, i've updated the basePath and assetPrefix. But it seems that is not enough. If anyone can help me, it will be really helpful for me.

Comment: please provide the code you use `react-dom` this is closely related to whether the application will run

Comment: For testing i was using freshly created nextjs project. You can choose that as a starting point?

Comment: you are trying to deploy new application on domain `domain.com/<app-name>` right?

Comment: Yes. domain.com/frontend for example